# Using subprocess.check_output for a command with 2>/dev/null

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I am on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 and Python 2.7.

If I type the following: `du -g -d1 /Users 2> /dev/null` in the command line, everything works perfectly.

Now, my goal is to use that command in a python script.

My idea was to use the following:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users', '/dev/null'])
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./verifications.py", line 1, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users', '/dev/null'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users', '/dev/null']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Also, when I run `subprocess.check_output(['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users', '/dev/null'])` in local everything works fine, the error happens when I am logged on a shared iMac using Apple's Shared Screen tool. I have a feeling that the problem might be due to permissions, but I cannot find anything.

Comment: `>/dev/null` is a redirection, not an argument. That is to say, it tells the shell how to set up file descriptors for the command before running it, and isn't actually passed to the `du` command at all.

Comment: ...oh -- earlier in your question you use `2>/dev/null`. That means something different. Please try to be consistent.

Comment: But this is still how https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html uses it.

Comment: That documentation is passing a literal argument, not performing a redirection. That is to say, it's running `ls -l /dev/null`, not `ls -l >/dev/null` or `ls -l 2>/dev/null`. The three are completely different commands.

Comment: Ohhh so I think I am mixing things up a little bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `2>/dev/null`, the appropriate way to control redirection of file descriptor 2 with the `subprocess.Popen` family of calls is `stderr=`:

```
# Python 2.x, or 3.0-3.2
output = subprocess.check_output(['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users'],
                                 stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
```

...or, with a Python supporting `subprocess.DEVNULL`:

```
# Python 3.3 or newer
output = subprocess.check_output(['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users'],
                                  stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

---

By the way, personally, I'd suggest something more like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
  raise Exception(stderr)
```

...which, instead of sending `stderr` to `/dev/null`, keeps it around to use in generating a useful exception in the event that the command fails. (Pick an appropriate subclass of Exception, obviously).

Comment: Not sure if I understood right, but this is what I get now:

>>> import subprocess

>>> output = subprocess.check_output(['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users'], stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 529, in check_output
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.

Comment: Reread the answer (and reload, if your browser hasn't kept up with edits). You'll note that I'm using `stderr=`, not `stdout=`. stdout is FD 1 -- it's what `>/dev/null` redirects, and, as I said before removing that section entirely, that redirection doesn't make sense with `check_output()`.

Comment: Let's say we forget my idea. How would you perform du -g -d1 /Users 2> /dev/null in a python script? /edit I need to catch the result so I can use it later in the script.

Comment: Personally, I'd collect both stdout and stderr -- throwing away error messages rather than recording them to use in an exception is silly. And doing that, one can use the `communicate()` call.

Comment: I'm still getting >>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.check_output(['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users'],
...                                  stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['du', '-g', '-d1', '/Users']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: See the edit, which collects stderr to generate an exception that describes *why* the command failed (since knowing only the exit status is rather spectacularly useless). I don't know your operating system, so I don't know which `du` flags are valid on it, so I can't predict the error without knowing stderr.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I might be wrong, but doesn't the `subprocess.check_output(..., stderr=open(...))` leak a file descriptor? I would tend to prefer `with open(...) as null: subprocess.check_output(..., stderr=null)`...

Comment: @twalberg, garbage collection is a beautiful thing. But, yes, if we can't afford an indeterminate delay before close (maybe we're doing a lot of calls of this sort?), then that would be preferable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, I guess that's the sort of thing that happens when a C and C++ programmer picks up Python, rather than learning Python first... I tend to rely on garbage collection as little as possible...

Comment: @twalberg, I *have* had a Python program using this idiom run out of available FDs before garbage collection kicked in... three jobs or so ago. As such, the warning isn't entirely off-base. :)

Comment: This is the exception I get using your suggestion: Exception: du: /Users/*****/.ssh: Permission denied

Comment: @A.P., that's a problem with the permissions you have when you're calling `du`, not a problem with my code. You need to fix it yourself.

Comment: @A.P., ...by contrast, if you want to ignore errors (like directories you can't read), then you shouldn't be using a `check_`*-series call, which treats all errors as fatal. Think about if you were writing this in bash and used `set -e`; it would fail at the same place, and for the same reason.

Comment: There is something I do not understand. I have the permissions to use du -g -d1 /Users 2> /dev/null (it works perfectly). But then when I want to execute the same (equivalent) command in a python script (using your suggestion), I get permission denied. Any idea why?

Comment: @A.P., it's not a permission denied running the command, it's a permission denied when the command gets to that specific directory. When you use `2>/dev/null`, you throw away the error message so you don't see that it's happening, but the error happens in both cases.

Comment: @A.P., do this in your shell: `if du -g -d1 /Users 2> /dev/null; then echo "SUCCESS!"; else echo "FAILURE!"; fi`, and see which one it emits.

Comment: But I thought stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w') would also throw away the error and output would receive the part without any error?

Comment: @A.P., throwing away the error *message* doesn't throw away the exit status; the error still happens even if you can't see it. Did you actually run the command I gave you in a shell? What did it emit?

Comment: Obviously it outputs the error. Thing is I have access to first depth of /Users, which is all I need. But du -g -d1 /Users goes deeper than first subdirectories, which is the problem I think.

Comment: If you want an accurate total size of `/Users` *and all its subdirectories*, you need +rx to *all its subdirectories*. Can't get around that. If all you have `+rx` permissions to is `/Users`, you can only get the size of files in /Users itself, and that's not very helpful. Anyhow, this is now totally off-topic; questions about what permissions you need to use `du` should be asked separately (maybe on http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/). If you want to ignore the error and accept inaccurate results, do the obvious thing and take out the `raise Exception`.